# How do I update table1 using inner joins ,where conditions along with limit

Tags: mysql, join

Here is my query where I want to update table1 field based on matched with table2 column value

Conditions I want to apply for update query are:

1. where table1.field is null
2. limit/ top 1000 records

Query I used to perform this operation is

```
update table1 t1
set t1.BaseAcqId =
   (
    select t2.BaseAcqId from table2 t2
    inner join t1 on t1.DateTime=t2.DateTime
    where t1.BaseAcqId is null limit 100
  );
```

Error:

1. wrong usage LIMIT with UPdate
2. Performance slow if I remove LIMIT
3. total count of records in both the table is 30 million

Comment: Have you added an index on your foreign keys?

Comment: Yes. I have added index on foreign keys as wel as primary keys.

Comment: ["For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: is there any way I can use limit with inner join and update?

Comment: You could insert the limited results into a temp table, and join against that. No longer a single query, but can accomplish the task.

Comment: Try to set an indes on BaseAcqId too and remove the limit. Besides: there is no need for a primary key to be indexed. With the primary key there comes a clustered index, this means the table is physically sorted by the primary key. A well placed index should deal with 30 million records. But if this does not work for you, you can define a procedure wich handles the update with limits

Comment: I'm confused. I think you cannot specify target table1 in "from" clausule in inner select. MySql prevents it. Moreover, I dont understand, what is your goal? Expression set t1.BaseAcqId = expects a scalar value (one value), but your inner select returns the set of values. I think you cannot set a set of values to one value. It will call "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Comment: update table1 set BaseAcqId =
(select BaseAcqId from table2 
where table2.DateTime=table1.DateTime limit 1)
where BaseAcqId is null limit 1000;

is there any good way for the better performance ??

Comment: yes my subquery returns more than 1 row. so here is modified code

update table1 set BaseAcqId = 
(select BaseAcqId from table2 
where table2.DateTime=table1.DateTime limit 1) 
where BaseAcqId is null limit 1000;